# Converse of renaming substitutions

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, substitution

In the paper *Theory Unification in Abstract Clause Graphs*, Hans Jorgen Ohlbach states that, given the renaming substitution $\sigma$, the converse substitution $\sigma^{c}$ is defined as $x=\sigma(y) \leftrightarrow y=\sigma^{c}(x)$, for all variables $x$ in the set of variables $V$. Example: if $\sigma = \{x \mapsto x', y\mapsto y'\}$, then the converse $\sigma_{c} = \{x' \mapsto x, y'\mapsto y\}$. The author concludes that, if $\sigma$ is a renaming substitution, then $\sigma\sigma^{c} = \sigma$ and $\sigma^{c}\sigma = \sigma^{c}$. This conclusion is not clear to me, since, as far as I can tell, $\sigma\sigma^{c} = \sigma^{c}$ and $\sigma^{c}\sigma = \sigma$. For instance, using the same example above, considering $\sigma = \{x \mapsto x', y\mapsto y'\}$, then

$\sigma\sigma^{c} = $

$\{x \mapsto x', y\mapsto y'\}\{x' \mapsto x, y'\mapsto y\} = $

$\{x \mapsto x, y \mapsto y, x' \mapsto x, y'\mapsto y\} =$

$\{x' \mapsto x, y'\mapsto y\} =$

$\sigma^{c}$.

Could someone help me understand how the author concludes that $\sigma\sigma^{c} = \sigma$ and $\sigma^{c}\sigma = \sigma^{c}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that we are speaking of "repeated substitution".

Then, with *term* $t(x,y)$ and the above substitutions we have:

> $\sigma(t(x,y))=t(x',y')$ and thus: $\sigma^c[\sigma(t(x,y))]=\sigma^c[t(x',y')]=t(x,y)$.

But $\sigma^c(t(x,y))=t(x,y)$, because there are no $x',y'$ in $t$, and thus: $\sigma^c\sigma=\sigma^c$.

In the same way:

> $\sigma^c(t(x,y))=t(x,y)$ and thus: $\sigma[\sigma^c(t(x,y))]=\sigma[t(x,y)]=t(x',y')$ which is $\sigma(t)$.

Thus: $\sigma\sigma^c=\sigma$

Comment: Mr Allegranza, when you say that $\sigma^c[\sigma(t(x,y))]=\sigma^c[t(x',y')]=t(x,y)$, you are substituting from the right to the left side. First, $\sigma(t(x,y))$ and then $\sigma^c[t(x',y')]$. I thought that the composition of substitutions should be read from left to right, as it is in the wikipedia's article on substitution. Do you know which reading direction is more common in the literature?